# Top of the world achievement

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I can't get the game to recognize that I built to the world limit. I saved and closed out. But still no luck. I'm in my son's realm: is that the reason it won't work?

Comment: In what way should it recognise that you built to the world limit? Are you using a datapack that adds an advancement for this? Or do you mean that you can just keep building higher and higher? That would be a very strange bug and potentially exploitable, therefore very interesting.

Comment: I assume the OP is asking about this achievement: https://www.xboxachievements.com/game/minecraft-windows-10-edition/achievement/163859-Top-of-the-World.html - It is available for (as far as I can tell) at least the windows 10 and xbox editions of minecraft. Not the java version of minecraft. @KeyGold69922145 are you asking about the Windows 10/Xbox versions? :)

Comment: @Elva I added the Minecraft tag, because the game wasn't mentioned in the original post. I based it on the OP mentioning a 'world limit', and a 'realm', and a quick 'Top of the World' achievement search. But it might not be about Minecraft - or this particular version - at all.

Comment: I checked the Edit History and saw that the Java tag was added by @Joachim even if is not valid. It can be Java or Bedrock on any of their platforms, and this was never mentioned by OP. I'm voting to close as "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: @Lemon That's what I mentioned in the comment before yours :)

Answer (score 0):

The world’s limit must be reached via scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this achievement requires reaching the sky limit with scaffolding. Fortunately, you can build all the way up, minus the top block with any regular material (dirt, cobble, etc), and then use scaffolding for the very last block, and the achievement should pop*.

*Some achievements in this game are slightly bugged and sometimes don't pop. I've had a few like this. In my experience, if you're sure you've accomplished the tasks in the achievement, you can either attempt it again, or you may have to start a new world and do it again. Obviously this isn't a great solution, but until the game stops being bugged, there's not much that can be done besides this. Best of luck.